# Dropdown menu inside column is not getting properly rendered when there are less number of rows

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, datatables

I am trying to show a drop-down menu inside of the datatables.

When there are sufficient rows in the datatable, dropdown menu appears normally:

[image]

When there are not enough rows, dropdown menu gets hidden behind datatable:

[image]

I guess, this problem happens because `overflow` property of `.dataTables_scrollHead` and `.dataTables_scrollBody` is set to `auto`. I tried changing to `visible` and then drop-down appears properly but then the top level buttons like "export" / "search" etc. become un-clickable.

Tried setting high `z-index` value on drop-down menu, but that also does not help.

How can I fix this?

---

Adding a demo:

Please see 4'th column from last viz. "Last actioned":   http://live.datatables.net/jocotuze/24

Comment: Akshay, if its possible, either give us the url or code with working example so we can debug, this is something which needs debugging, and without the working example, we can't help you

Comment: @AwsmeSandy: Here you go (please see 4'th column from last viz. "Last actioned"):   http://live.datatables.net/jocotuze/24

Comment: Here we are using table scroll too, so with this of course we can't make it visible, the best and the shortest method is to give the Table container 'dataTables_scrollBody' a minimum hight like 300px, so the dropdown will be fully visible http://live.datatables.net/jocotuze/28/


The other way, which is a bit tricky too, if you make the dropdown fixed position, then it can be fully visible, but in that case, you have to check the offset positions of the clicked button, and assign those postion value to the dropdown to position it just below the button.

Comment: @AwsmeSandy For the first option, my dropdown is configurable by users so I can’t know how much “minimum height” to specify. Could you give some illustration about second option you mentioned? Thanks

Comment: Here is the best example for you https://codepen.io/andykono/pen/WvPgvz may be this will help you